# how to fetch the particular records in rally grid with the keyword matching with particular column?

Tags: gridview, rally

This is my grid.

```
this.grid = Ext.create("Rally.ui.grid.Grid", {
    columnLines: !0,
    border: !1,
    store: this.stores,
    columnCfgs: [
        {text: "Region", dataIndex: "Project"},
        {text: "Launch  Date", dataIndex: "lDate"},
        {text: "Program Name", dataIndex: "Name", width: 500 }, 
        {text: "Length of Program",dataIndex: "ProgramLength", width: 150 }, 
        {text: "Revenue", dataIndex: "Revenue"},
        {text: "Defects", dataIndex: "NormalDefects"}
    ]
})
```

My grid is loaded with some 200 records and 10/Per page. After the grid has loaded, - want to display only the records which are going to match the Keyword.

For Example, I want to display the records which are matching the **program name**="*first project*"

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Take a look at _getFilter() method in this example, where a grid can be filtered by one or two drodpdown fields: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/example/DefectDashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rally grid has a [filter](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.grid.Grid-method-filter) method which you should be able to use to reload the grid:

```
this.grid.filter(Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
    property: 'Name',
    operator: '=',
    value: 'First Project'
}), true, true);
```

Comment: Error: Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically. Missing required class: Rally.data.wsapi.Filter. this is the error am getting :(

Comment: This was renamed from Rally.data.QueryFilter in 2.0rc2.  If you are using an older version of the sdk you should continue to use Rally.data.QueryFilter.